# lucene search is not working

Tags: lucene

I am using Lucene for my user search. For indexing i have the following code

```
private void internalAddUser(User user) throws IOException {
    Document document = new Document();
    document.add(new Field("login", user.getLogin(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    document.add(new Field("firstName", user.getFirstName(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    document.add(new Field("lastName", user.getLastName(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    userIndexWriter.addDocument(document);
}
```

and for search I use the following code but i am not getting any results.

```
@Override
@Cacheable("user-prefix-cache")
public Collection<String> searchUserByPrefix(String prefix) {
    IndexSearcher searcher = null;
    List<String> logins = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        searcher = userSearcherManager.acquire();

        BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();

        Query query1 = new TermQuery(new Term("login", prefix));
        Query query2 = new TermQuery(new Term("firstName", prefix));
        Query query3 = new TermQuery(new Term("lastName", prefix));

        booleanQuery.add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
        booleanQuery.add(query2, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
        booleanQuery.add(query3, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

        SortField sortField = new SortField("login", SortField.STRING, true);
        Sort sort = new Sort(sortField);

        TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(booleanQuery, DEFAULT_TOP_N_SEARCH_USER, sort);
        int totalHits = topDocs.totalHits;
        if (totalHits == 0) {
            return new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        ScoreDoc[] scoreDocArray = topDocs.scoreDocs;
        for (int i = 0; i < scoreDocArray.length; i++) {
            int documentId = scoreDocArray[i].doc;
            Document document = searcher.doc(documentId);
            logins.add(document.get("login"));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("A Lucene query had a I/O error : " + e.getMessage());
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            userSearcherManager.release(searcher);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("The Lucene searcher could not be given back to the searcherManager pool. " +
                    e.getMessage());

            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return logins;
}
```

I am not a lucene expect but i am not sure why it is not working. Does anybody have any idea.

```
[DEBUG] in.daydiary.web.rest.SearchController - REST request to find users starting with : j
[DEBUG] in.daydiary.web.rest.SearchController - REST request to find users starting with : j
[DEBUG] in.daydiary.web.rest.SearchController - REST request to find users starting with : ju
[DEBUG] in.daydiary.web.rest.SearchController - REST request to find users starting with : jul
[DEBUG] in.daydiary.web.rest.SearchController - REST request to find users starting with : juli
[DEBUG] in.daydiary.web.rest.SearchController - REST request to find users starting with : julia
[DEBUG] in.daydiary.web.rest.SearchController - REST request to find users starting with : julianb
[DEBUG] in.daydiary.web.rest.SearchController - REST request to find users starting with : julianb
[DEBUG] in.daydiary.web.rest.SearchController - REST request to find users starting with : julian
[DEBUG] in.daydiary.web.rest.SearchController - REST request to find users starting with : julia
[DEBUG] in.daydiary.web.rest.SearchController - REST request to find users starting with : juli
[DEBUG] in.daydiary.web.rest.SearchController - REST request to find users starting with : jul
[DEBUG] in.daydiary.web.rest.SearchController - REST request to find users starting with : ju
[DEBUG] in.daydiary.web.rest.SearchController - REST request to find users starting with : j
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things look suspect here.

All your fields are `Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED`.  This means they will not be tokenized, but rather will only match an exact match on the entire field, as you are searching here.  This will be case-sensitive as well.  Seeing exactly what data is indexed, and what you are querying for would help understanding whether this is actually the problem.

Second, your method's name indicates you want a prefix search, but you aren't using a prefix search.  A `TermQuery` will only get exact matches.  A [`PrefixQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PrefixQuery.html) would be used to search by prefix, which is used exactly like a TermQuery:

```
    Query query1 = new PrefixQuery(new Term("login", prefix));
    booleanQuery.add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

Comment: I have a search box...so i want the moment the user starts typing for example it must start searching. My login contains a email id, firstName for example peter , lastName for example foo.

Comment: Like I said, you should be using `PrefixQuery`, and it is likely that Analysis will be needed here as well.

Comment: Okay, let me just throw out a blind guess here.  The indexed value starts with a capital letter?  Or it could be two words long, contain punctuation, or a number of other problems.  If you index with `Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED`, you will only get EXACT matches on that content.  If you want it to be tokenized, case-insensitive, etc. you need to Analyze the field.

Comment: Yeah i changed it to ANALYZED ALSO but still no results...is there a way i can see if there is some indexed data also or not...

Answer (score 0):

**First.** Care to provide the lucene version.

**Second.** You can certainly see the indexes. Get luke of the same version as that of Lucene..You will be able to see the indexed data inside luke.. Run it just by executing java -jar jarname.

**Third.** Check if the **Analyzer** used during the indexing process and analyzer used during the searching process is same.. This is a very common mistake made by everyone.

**Fourth.** Since you are not getting hit, please refer this excellent link which mentions some points which might be leading to no HITS found.

http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Why_am_I_getting_no_hits_.2F_incorrect_hits.3F